# jquery validation plugin addClass to invalid fields

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation

Is there a way to add a class to all inputs of a form that returned invalid when using jquery's validation plugin?

If so, how?

Comment: The plugin automatically applies the error class to any required field that fails validation.

Comment: @surrealdreams I feel miserably stupid. Thank you!

Comment: No worries.  Got to know what you don't know sometimes.  That's when you learn something new!  Go ahead and accept BenjaminHarris' answer, he explained it a lot further that I did. +1 to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Surreal Dreams said, the validator plugin will automatically apply an error class to the failed fields. But you can customize this. There are [several hooks](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) (error-related and other) you can use in your validation code. Here are a couple that are relevant for your question:

- `errorClass`

  > "Use this class to create error labels, to look for existing error
  >   labels and to add it to invalid elements."
- `errorPlacement`

  > "Customize placement of created error labels. First argument: The
  >   created error label as a jQuery object. Second argument: The invalid
  >   element as a jQuery object."

Here's an example:

```
$("whatever").validate({
    errorClass: "yourErrorClassHere",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        // You can do all sorts of stuff to the individual error elements, like adding classes
    }
});
```

Comment: Way to take my little comment and explain it properly.  Nicely done.